# Angular 1.6 ng-Repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a small Angular 1.6 app (can't upgrade to latest version), and i need to make a ngRepeat.

So i do this :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="test in exp.experiments" checked value="{{test.well}}"/>
```

But this doesn't work :/
No error, and nothing in the screen.

I think this is the exp.experiments, but when i console.log it there is some values. And some other values like :

```
{{exp.barcode}}
```

Are working.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: try ng-value="test.well"

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use annotation when binding, try

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="test in exp.experiments" checked ng-value="test.well"/>
```